# How can I shorten my URLs in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, url

For example I am using following URLs for user profile/dashboard:

```
example.com/person/person/profile
example.com/person/person/dashboard
```

Where **person** is **module**, 2nd **person** is **controller** and **profile** and **dashboard** are **actions**.

But I want that If user go to following URLs then they should point the same URLs respectively mentioned above:

```
example.com/person/profile
example.com/person/dashboard
```

Is there any way that I always remove the module name from URL? Remember I want to keep the current directory structure.

Thanks

Comment: I find person a relatively bad module name and if the module is called person or user then there should be no need for a controller with the same name. The controller names should then be an entity below the user level. Like /user/account/login or /user/profile/edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using routes, in your bootstrap add this

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.ini');
    $router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
    $router->addConfig($config, 'routes');
    Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setRouter($router);
}
```

Then in your config director create a file called `routes.ini`, this will contain your custom routes, try these

```
routes.person_profile.route = "person/profile"
routes.person_profile.defaults.controller = person
routes.person_profile.defaults.action = profile
routes.person_profile.defaults.module = person

routes.person_dashboard.route = "person/dashboard"
routes.person_dashboard.defaults.controller = person
routes.person_dashboard.defaults.action = dashboard
routes.person_dashboard.defaults.module = person
```

Here we define two routes, remeber to give each a unique name I have called these `person_profile` and `person_dashboard`.

The `route` value is the URI which will be overwritten by the `controller`, `action` and `module` values, for example the route `person/profile` will be automatically dispatched to the `person` controller, the `person` module and the `profle` action.

Hope that helps.